# A rest parameter must be of an array type - typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

when i try to create build using ionic `cordova build android --prod` i am getting errors with too many lines in file `typescript: node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts, line: 6695`

> A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>
> L6673:          prependOnceListener(event: "finish", listener: () =>
>   void): this;

and this cause the failure of building the APK.i am not sure about what is wrong,but without using --prod,it works

```
>ionic info
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v9.2.1
    npm  : 5.5.1 
    OS   : Linux 4.4

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: It's possible you're using an out-of-date version of TypeScript that's running into parse errors. What version are you using?

Comment: I have added the output of ionic info,the app script veriosn is 3.1.8 @DanielRosenwasser

Comment: Consider running `npm install --save-dev @types/node@ts2.4` to get a version of `@types/node` that's compatible with TypeScript 2.4 and see if that fixes it.